# How to resolve computer not starting up after update to Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, uefi, client

I've recently made a computer for my mom and since she was used to Ubuntu, I've installed the 22.04 lts on it.
It has been working fine, no problems with anything until she installed updates today and when trying to restart she could not get past the filesystem check and after initially loading it would eventually disappear and she'd have a black screen with an underscore in the top left of her screen. So basically she cannot use her desktop.

For the computer specs they're:

- Ryzen 7 5700x CPU
- b-550 f WiFi mb
- Corsair Vengeance lpx 2x32gb 3600mhz
- GTX 1650 d6 Windforce 4gb oc
- Samsung pro 2tb M2

What I've actually tried so far:

- Went into UEFI tried to find a safe mode boot (didn't find one)
- Hit my escape button like a madman, shortly seeing the boot menu (one where you would pick Ubuntu safe mode and so on) then it disappearing and seeing grub 2.06. I tried some commands but honestly I have no idea.

I've got some basic knowledge about Ubuntu and sudo and making dirs and so on but it's very basic.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Xelren

Comment: A filesystem check may suggest there is a proble with the storage device, which may need to be replaced. You may want to try to boot from an Ubuntu  installation USB, and run a filesystem check manually on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: So it's the first time I installed an Ubuntu client. All the parts were new from last month, the filesystem check has happened since I installed 22.04 the first day and every time I started it up. I honestly thought it was just regular proceeding. But the problem really did arise only at the point where my mom accepted an Ubuntu update yesterday.

Comment: You get to the grub boot menu by tapping ONCE on the ESC key when the BIOS/UEFI texts are visible. Select "Recovery mode"; for the latest version kernel, run fsck and networking menu entries, then drop to a root shell (an extra tap on Enter required). There then look into any problems told about by `dmesg | less` - and further in the `/var/log/*` files where `zcat filename | less` will show the content of compressed *.gz files. Also do `lsblk -ape7 -o+FSUSE%` and verify that all partitions has free space.